# Using VB .NET, find and replace a number in a string with zero

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem to find a number in a string and replace this with the number "0". The string I use is

```
Dim RichtextboxA As String = "Marlon  2  4  7  8"
Dim RichtextboxA1 As String = " 13  22  24  26  31  33"
```

from a textbox.

I get the input say: 2 and now I want to replace this 2 in the string with "0".
I use the following code:

```
RichtextboxA = RichtextboxA.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "0")
RichtextboxA1 = RichtextboxA1.Replace(TextBox2.Text, "0")
```

and put the outcome in a new string.

This will do, but what has happened is the following: The 2 will be replaced but also the 22 and 24 by 00 and 04 and that's not what I want. I want only the 2 replaced by 0 and then replace 22 or 24 or 4 by 0 but don't know how.

Because the replace code works with characters the find locates 2 as single character.

I also tried to do this with regex but this will give the same results.

Sorry for my bad English but I hope that somebody can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do a regex replacement on `\b2\b` to target the number 2 as a standalone word:

```
Dim Input as string = "Hello 1 2 and goodbye 22 24"
Dim Replacement as string = "0"
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(Input, "\b" + YourTextBox.Text + "\b", Replacement)
Console.WriteLine(result)  ' Hello 1 0 and goodbye 22 24
```

I assume above you have a text box called `YourTextBox` which contains the 2 input or whatever value you want to replace.